# WSO2 EI - ERROR - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01483: invalid length for DATE or NUMBER bind variable

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am getting following Registry Exception exception while trying to start WSO2 EI server.The server configurations were working fine and started showing this error recently.Some details from error log is as below.

```
 [2020-07-22 12:18:47,493] [-1234] [] [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dao.JDBCResourceDAO} -  Failed to write resource content to the database.
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01483: invalid length for DATE or NUMBER bind variable

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    -------
[2020-07-22 12:18:47,493] [-1234] [] [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.theme.mgt.util.ThemeUtil} -  Error loading theme to the sytem registry for registry path: /repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.all-themes/Default/images
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Unable to put resource Failed to write resource content to the database.
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.put(MountHandler.java:299)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.put(HandlerManager.java:2503)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.put(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:204)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.put(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:949)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:705)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.putInternal(UserRegistry.java:828)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$1000(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:804)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$11.run(UserRegistry.java:801)
```

What can be the root cause of the issue and How can I debug the error?

Comment: It is better if you can share the scheduled task configuration (masking sensitive information) to your question. It might help provide others' opinion

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply.I think the issue is not related to schedule task,I removed all the car files from deploy folder and tried to restart the server but getting error as above.

Comment: What variables are added to the registry? It seems that one of them is malformed in some way? Did you update anything in registry recently?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.We have configured some registry variables for html,xslt etc which are custom for the project.There are no recent changes ,but I tried remove the existing Registry resource car file and tried to restart the server ,also tried to deploy working car file,but issue still exists.How can I debug more to see which resource entry is malformed ? Or how to revert back the registry changes which may have caused malformation of entry ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following alternative workaround available to resolve the issue.

Navigate to the <EI_HOME>/resources/ folder.
Rename the allthemes directory to the **allthemes1**.
Restart the server and check you could resolve the issue.

Comment: the error message around the themes is gone after renaming the themes folder..but this issue still persists